# Determining thickness of Aluminium foil with alpha particles

Tags: nuclear-physics

So I'm trying to derive an equation to determine the thickness of a thin aluminium foil using Bragg Kleeman rule. I've so far got that the range of the alpha particles in aluminium is $R(Al)=R(air)\frac{Density(Air)}{Density(Al)}\sqrt{\frac{Atomic no.(Al)}{Atomic no.(air)}}$.

From here I am unsure where I can derive an expression for the thickness of the foil unless it involves the fraction of the ranges in aluminium over air? I'm not too sure, any help would be greatly appreciated. Feel free to edit my qeustion for clarity. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you get a ratio to air. In the old days (think Rutherford) this was reasonable since they measured relative energy by looking at the range in air. These days there are better ways to do it, mainly through using various stopping power measurements and theories.